# Getting viso2_ros to work - visual odometry-

Tags: ros, viso2-ros, libviso2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

there exists a c++ open-source visual odometry library called "LIBVISO2" (cvlibs.net/software/libviso/)
which I would like to use in ROS.  For the library there exists a ROS-package called "viso2_ros" which
is a ROS-wrapper for the library.

I am totally new to LINUX and ROS. In Windows I use VS2010 and the Flycap drivers for the two Point Grey Flea3  "gigE cameras" making the stereo-visual odometry work (using LIBVISO2).

Now I finished the 20 ROS beginner tutorials but still am confused how to get started.
Can you give me some tips regarding how to take the first steps?

Basically I need a tip how to

- establish a camera node (with the Flea Linux drivers??) which will output images (I use a trigger)
- rectify the images (I have all the parameters for initundistorstrectifymap from opencv)
- use openCV in general
- make my fist steps with viso2_ros

Thank You. All tips are well appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/174894/getting-viso2_ros-to-work----visual-odometry-/) by [mister_kay](https://answers.ros.org/users/18994/mister_kay/) on ROS Answers with karma: 238 on 2014-06-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi mister_kay,

first of all, wellcome to the ROS comunity. In order to start with you application, I'd first take a look at what drivers are already available in ROS. If I'm not mistaken, ptgrey Flea3 admits IIDC protocol, so maybe you can use the [camera1394](http://wiki.ros.org/camera1394) driver, or tweak it a little bit so that you can use it with your usb3 camera, even if it's not firewire. Take a look [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/90586/flea3-usb3-camera-and-camera1394-package/).

Check that you can get your images published as ROS topics. Once that's been done, then the rectificacion can be done with the node [image_proc](http://wiki.ros.org/image_proc). Once you get these two nodes on, calibrate the camera with the [camera calibrator](http://wiki.ros.org/camera_calibration/Tutorials/MonocularCalibration) and you'll be ready to rock with opencv. If you prefer, you can also rectify the images from opencv directly. It's your call.

Then, finally, for [viso2 and viso2_ros](http://wiki.ros.org/viso2_ros?distro=hydro) follow the example launchfile. Another way to test viso2 is to download our bagfile (there a link in the wiki, if not, download it from [here](ftp://opt.uib.es/bagfiles/viso2_ros/)) and launch the demo launchfile.

---

Originally posted by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) with karma: 1471 on 2014-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mister_kay](https://answers.ros.org/users/18994/mister_kay/) on 2014-07-01**:
Thank you very much Miquel! With your help I installed the Point Grey driver and can now display the imgs from my cameras (for some reason with a low frequ. in my virtual  machine). Also the "roslaunch camera.launch" command created many topics. One question: Where can I find the example launchfile?

**Comment by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) on 2014-07-02**:
In github you have the whole repo: https://github.com/srv/viso2 and the example launchfile: https://github.com/srv/viso2/blob/hydro/viso2_ros/launch/demo.launch.